# Find $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x -x -1}{1-\cos(x)}$ with taylor

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x  -x -1}{1-\cos(x)}$$ with taylor

### My try and stuck

let $$ f(x) = e^x - x -1$$
and
$$ g(x) = 1-\cos(x)$$

Now, I am taylor pattern with penao rest for $f$:

$$f'(x) = e^x - 1 \rightarrow f'(0)=0 \\
 f''(x) = e^x  \rightarrow f''(0)=1 $$
and futher there is the same situation so I stop there. Ok - now $g$:
$$g'(x) = 1+\sin(x) \rightarrow g'(0)=1 $$
$$g''(x) = 1+\cos(x) \rightarrow g''(0)=2 $$
Ok, I stop there too because I want to have the same degree

$$  \frac{e^x  -x -1}{1-\cos(x)} = \frac{0+0+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{r(x)}{x^2}}{0+x+\frac{2}{2!}x^2 + p(x)} = \\
\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{r(x)}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x}+1+\frac{p(x)}{x^2}}$$

and there I stuck - what can be done with $\frac{1}{x}$ in the denominator?

Comment: Don't forget the derivative of a constant is $0$ (you seem to recognize this in the numerator but fail to utilize it in differentiating the denominator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be 
$g'(x) = \sin(x) $ and $g''(x) = \cos(x)$

Comment: god kill me - I am going to fix that and update a post - I have lost 45 min at looking for a mistake

Comment: Ok - that solved the problem - I am going to choose that as the best - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arround zero, $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(x))$$
and
$$1-\cos(x)\sim \frac{x^2}{2}$$

thus, the limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(x))}{\frac{x^2}{2}}=1$$